# How can we display ModelAndView model value in a jsp page in a popup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a jsp submit-cot.jsp from where I hit the controller below and the form is sucessfully submitted, and I am redirected to the submit-cot.jsp page again.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitform(
            ModelAndView model,
            @ModelAttribute("cot") Cot cot,
            @ModelAttribute("platformUrl") PlatformUrlView platformUrl,
            final HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        cotService.save(cot,platformUrl);
        model.setViewName("redirect:/submit-cot");
        model.addObject("msg", resource.getMsg("A45"));
        return model;
    }
```

The problem is that the message 'msg' comes in the url, as 
    http://localhost:8080/submit-cot?msg=Cot+is+submitted+successfully.
I need to display the message 'msg' in a popup.

Can anybody please suggest how to get the message in a popup.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters you want in the model object itself. model.addAttribute(key, value). This will be available in the JSP. Use ${keyname} to retrieve the attribute in the client side and display it. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing a redirect from your Controller, the default redirect mechanism will add the attribute's value to be appended to the url as that is the only way to be able to maintain the value across a request-response-request cycle without maintaining a server side session.

The solution to your problem is to use Spring's flash attributes feature which is specifically meant to solve this.

You can change your controller code as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView submitform(
        ModelAndView model,
        @ModelAttribute("cot") Cot cot,
        @ModelAttribute("platformUrl") PlatformUrlView platformUrl,
        final HttpServletRequest request
        final RedirectAttributes redirAttr)
{
    cotService.save(cot,platformUrl);

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
    redirectView.setUrl("/submit-cot");
    redirAttr.addAttribute("msg", resource.getMsg("A45"));

    return redirectView;
}
```

In your Controller code for processing the "/submit-cot" url, you can retrieve the value using RequestContextUtils and set it in the ModelAndView for further processing. Example below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit-cot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView submitCot(
        ModelAndView model,
        final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    model.setViewName("popup-view");

    Map<String, ?> flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
    if (flashMap != null) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
    }

    return model;
}
```

Finally, in your view, you can place your logic for conditionally displaying the popup.

Documentation link for further reading - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes